# Trying to obtain a list of players belonging to the same league through two tables without a direct key link

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

My question is an academic one about how to obtain a list of players having the same `CurrentTeamId` from another list of teams having the same `CurrentLeagueId` in order to display a list of players belonging to the same `CurrentLeagueId`.

But the `Player` class doesn't have the `CurrentLeagueId` property; the `Team` class does, of which the players are members.  The `Player` class has a `TeamId` foreign key property linking to the `Team` class, but not to the `League` class.

The class hierarchy, then, by way of navigation, is as follows: `League` -> `Team` -> `Player`.

The class hierarchy by way of foreign keys are in reverse: `Player` -> `Team` -> `League`

That means I need to first get a list of teams having the same `CurrentLeagueId`, of which they are members.  More than one team are members.

Then, from that list, obtain a list of all players belonging to each team having the same `TeamId`, which then is my goal. These are members of the league based on the same `CurrentLeagueId`.

Here is my code, which I'll admit probably isn't elegant, but it works up to a point:

```
public void BindPlayers_byLeague()
{
    using (var db = new SoccerDbContext())
    {
        IQueryable<Team> teams = db.Teams;
        IQueryable<Player> players = db.Players;

        //if any league is selected, then filter below.  Do not run if first run.
        //if first run, the whole list is displayed in the grid.  This also happens on form reset.
        if (0 < Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue) && !OKtoRun)
        {
            //get all the teams with the same CurrentLeagueId first,
            //based on currently selected league on league dropdownlist
            var leagueId = Convert.ToInt32(drp_Leagues1.SelectedValue);
            teams = teams.Where(t => t.CurrentLeagueId == leagueId);

            //display in team grid
            grd_Teams.DataSource = teams.ToList();
            grd_Teams.DataBind();

            //read it back in
            List<Team> eteam = (List<Team>)grd_Teams.DataSource;

            //obtain 
            foreach (Team teamitem in eteam)
            {
                int teamId = Convert.ToInt32(teamitem.TeamId);
                players = players.Where(t => t.CurrentTeamId == teamId);

            }
            //display in player grid
            grd_Players.DataSource = players.ToList();
            grd_Players.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

From the code above is the following result--this is the `grd_Players` grid:

[image: One of two table results]

And another table is generated after clicking on the Filter button--this is the `grd_Teams` grid:

[image: two of two table results]

Fairly obviously, this line of code is a problem because it's in a for loop:

```
players = players.Where(t => t.CurrentTeamId == teamId);
```

And it doesn't work, again because it's in a for loop.  (It works in the first loop, but not in the remaining loops.)  I'm trying to get a list of players belonging to each `TeamId` in the `teams` (small "t") list (there are 4 different `TeamId`s in there) and display it.  Hopefully, this presentation is clear enough to ask:  How can I improve the code? (For the purpose of displaying the player results in a grid, the `grd_Teams` grid is not necessary or required.)

For reference, below is the `Team` class:

```
 public class Team
    {
        public int TeamId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string TeamName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateEstablished { get; set; }

        //Navigation property -> Each team has many players
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

        //Navigation property -> Each team belongs to a specific league
        public League CurrentLeague { get; set; }

        //Foreignkey -> The associated LeagueId
        //[Required]
        [ForeignKey("CurrentLeague")]
        public int CurrentLeagueId { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548748%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var players = eteam.SelectMany(t => t.Players);
```